# How to update liveTile programatically on Windows8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to update my liveTile when application will enter background.How can I do ??

here is my code to update a liveTile.

```
    private static TileUpdater updater;        

public static void updateLiveTile(string text)
        {
            if (updater == null)
            {
                updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
            }
            else
                updater.Clear();

            updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

            var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImageAndText01);
            tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText = text;
            XmlNodeList tileImageAttributes = tile.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            ((XmlElement)tileImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appdata:///local/MyShop_Image.png");
            ((XmlElement)tileImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "red graphic");

            updater.Update(new TileNotification(tile));
        }
```

Comment: thanks Jamie ! now I update my question,please check the question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking how to do.  If you're in your application (where you can click on a button), you can't see your live tile.  If you're not in your application, then you can't update your live tile.

Comment: please forgive my awful explanation,I want to change the tile after application will enter background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consume [App tiles and badges sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148)  and [Tile updates from Background Task](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-updates-from-2f6a854c) helpful resources.

Comment: Please try not to just post links.  If the target pages disappear for some reason, this answer will become useless.  At least a summary of the information you link to would be helpful...

Comment: @ZombieSheep, that's more true with MSFT links. Added titles of samples to the links.